# Regular Expressions matching in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

I am trying to generate a regular expression match in Java, that accepts all numbers that contain **3 and 7** (in any order, ie there should be at least one 7 for all 3's and vice versa) over the set of integers. So far, I have written the code below, however I am not able to get the correct output. Any kind of help will be appreciated:

```
class Main {
  public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    System.out.println("333333".matches("[[3][7]+]*") ? "Yes" : "No");
  }
}
```

Here, I should be getting the output as NO, since the given string is only of 3's not of 3 and at least one 7.

Comment: I am sorry, but this is a module of some other task, which needs to be used. For a non computer science person, Java is easy to code, hence I'd like to stick to regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if a regex is necessary. Why not use the following:

```
public static boolean containsDigit(int n, int digit) {
    return String.valueOf(n).contains(String.valueOf(digit));
}

...

int n = 333333;
boolean nContains3And7 = containsDigit(n, 3) && containsDigit(n, 7);
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, this should be sufficient:

```
String input = "333333";
// Input string contains both a 3 and a 7.
System.out.println(((input.indexOf("3") > -1) && (input.indexOf("7") > -1)) ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Since a regex examines a sequence of characters, this exercise becomes unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 0):

`^(\d*3\d*7\d*)|(\d*7\d*3\d*)$` I think.